# How to move one directory back when path contains symlink

Tags: symbolic-link, thunar, cd-command

I want to move one directory back in Thunar when I get into by symbolic link. I know that in terminal I can use `cd -P` but I want to obtain this behavior in Thunar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a back button that will do just that. Enable it in the "view" menu. Set Location selector to "toolbar style".

Comment: You're writing about normal going up. I want to go up like using `cd -P ..` not `cd ..`.

Comment: I beleve there is an "up" that does cd .. and back which is like cd -

Comment: I have symlink on my desktop which name is "MySymlink". "MySymlink" point to `/home/winnfield/Stuff/`.
I'm clicking "MySymlink" and then I'm clicking "Go up" in Thunar. Now I'm in `/home/winnfield/Desktop/` (`cd ..`), but I want to be in `/home/winnfield/` (`cd -P ..`).

Comment: Ahh ok, that likely will not work because your "opening" thunar from the desktop. it has no history. So "back" has no where to go and "up" is pretty much cd .. . sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Ok, so it seems there is no solution for my problem. Could someone close this question, please?

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom action in Thunar that evaluates the current directory's physical path and opens a new thunar instance/window. The command is

```
thunar `pwd -P`
```

You can also associate a keyboard shortcut, as I did with `ctrl+p`.

It's not ideal because it opens a new thunar process/window...but I find it to be better than nothing.

[image: thunar custom action dialog]

In thunar preferences under `Behavior`, there is an option to `Open new thunar instances as tabs`, if you prefer this behavior.